# How i can create backup script from diagram in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I create a script from all object (tables / trigger / stored procedure / function ...) in my database.

I generated this script from SQL Server Management Studio.

I can recreate my database with this scrips on the other server.

But I miss all diagrams of my database after run my script for create another database.

Therefore, I need create backup script from all diagrams that exist in my database.

I need execute this script on the destination database for recreating all my diagrams.

I found this [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43076/Backup-SQL-Diagrams-In-Less-Than-5-Minutes). but i need some thinks that create all script (Insert Command) automatically.

Comment: Why don't you just create a backup of the database? I don't know of any way to script the diagrams, because there may be diagrams there that you don't have access to (e.g. if you didn't create them and you are not db_owner).

Comment: because i do not need data.

Comment: [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5997498/847990) I believe is a more complete script to go by for moving diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write this query and this work.

```
USE DestinationDatabase

DELETE  sysDiagrams
WHERE   name IN ( SELECT    name
              FROM      SourceDatabase.dbo.sysDiagrams )

SET IDENTITY_INSERT sysDiagrams ON

INSERT  sysDiagrams
    ( name ,
      principal_id ,
      diagram_id ,
      version ,
      definition
    )
    SELECT  name ,
            principal_id ,
            diagram_id ,
            version ,
            definition
    FROM    SourceDatabase.dbo.sysDiagrams

SET IDENTITY_INSERT sysDiagrams OFF
```

Comment: This script worked perfectly for me. A large diagram got corrupted and I could restore it from a copy in test-environment: This script saved me a lot of time.